# Add string to result of MySQL Count query

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select, count

I have a MySQL query I'm using inside Alpha Anywhere, a database app development tool. Here's the query:

```
SELECT  Count(*)  AS Expr1  FROM timelines
WHERE CaseName = :whichcases  AND
Custodian = :whichcustodians  AND  
Device = :whichdevices
```

The query works fine, but I need to add a string to the result. For example, if the query returns **352,133**, I'd like to add the string 'Total Records' to it, for a final result of **352,133 Total Records**.

I searched as thoroughly as possible before posting this question. I found quite a few topics that were close, but none really on point.

Answer (score 1):

I usually prefer to do such things on the application side, but if you positively have to do it in the query, you could use the [`concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
SELECT CONCAT(COUNT(*), ' Total Records') AS Expr1 
FROM   timelines 
WHERE  CaseName = :whichcases AND 
       Custodian = :whichcustodians AND
       Device = :whichdevices
```

Answer (score 0):

Immediately doing a concat like this:

```
SELECT concat(Count(*), ' total records') AS Expr1 
FROM   ...
```

will give a binary result in MySql version < 5.5.3 ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50fdf/28)). See also the 5.5 docs on [`concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

> Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments. May have one or more arguments. If all arguments are nonbinary strings, the result is a nonbinary string. If the arguments include any binary strings, the result is a binary string. A numeric argument is converted to its equivalent string form. This is a nonbinary string as of MySQL 5.5.3. **Before 5.5.3, it is a binary string**

NB: The fiddle shows the binary result, yet it is running on MySql 5.6.21. So you'll probably need a work-around for other versions as well.

One way to get around this, is to wrap the query:

```
SELECT concat(Expr1, ' total records') AS Expr1
FROM   ( 
     SELECT Count(*) AS Expr1 
     FROM   timelines
     WHERE  CaseName = :whichcases
        AND Custodian = :whichcustodians
        AND Device = :whichdevices
) as sub
```

Or you can use `CAST`:

```
SELECT concat(cast(count(*) as char), ' total records') as Expr1
FROM   timelines
WHERE  CaseName = :whichcases
   AND Custodian = :whichcustodians
   AND Device = :whichdevices
```

Comment: If you use MySQL <= 5.5.3 you can use CAST: SELECT CONCAT(CAST(Count(*) as dec), ' total records') AS Expr1 
FROM t;